# NullPointerException при передаче ArrayList из сервлета в JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: передаю в JSP ArrayList из сервлета с помощью request.setAttribute(), но при попытке получить элемент этого списка в JSP получаю NullPointerException.

Вот сервлет

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

File f = new File("Report_not_R5_updated.xlsx");
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

protected void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(f));
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Alarm");

    for(int r = 1; r<= sheet.getLastRowNum(); r++) {
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
        if((row.getCell(9).toString()).equals("Нет R5")) {
           list.add((row.getCell(3)).toString()); 
        }
    }
    request.setAttribute("answer", list);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp").forward(request, response);
    workbook.close();
}
}
```

Вот страничка JSP:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Автоматический подбор R5</title
</head>
<body>
<h2>Автоматический подбор R5</h2>
<form action="TestServlet" method="POST">
<button type="submit">Получить список</button>
</form>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%
ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("answer"); 
out.println(list.get(0));
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Если я просто вывожу на экран ArrayList (`out.println(list)`), то вижу, что он не пустой, в нем есть элементы. 
Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

Comment: Мне кажется,или вы сначала делаете запрос на jsp,а потом нажимаете на кнопку?Когда вы делаете запрос на jsp страницу,то у вас должен отобразиться ArrayList,но откуда ему взяться если вы не сделали запрос на сервлет?Вам нужно сделать в jsp проверку на пустоту ArrayList.Если = null , то не выводите его,а если != null то выводите.

Comment: @Sckoriy, ааа, вы правы. Я же сначала обращаюсь к JSP, и только после этого запускаю сервлет. Так и знал, что ошибка детская. Спасибо большое!

Comment: на самом деле лучше отделить java код от вью, так будет намного проще... и ещё правильнее будет так: List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
а ещё скорее сперва надо закрыть ресурс/поток и потом форвардить а не наоборот

Comment: @MuzaffarRasulov, спасибо за советы, учту. По поводу отделения кода от view, вы имеете ввиду, что лучше не использовать скриплеты в JSP? Из-за того, что такой код сложно поддерживать, или есть еще какие-то причины? Я просто не придумал, как это реализовать без кода в JSP.

Comment: @Eugene White, так точно. пользуйтесь jsp, этого никто не запрещает только без скриплетов вместо них воспользуйтесь с jstl тегами они намного упрощают и намного читабельным будет ваш код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В чем ошибка я, к сожалению, не скажу, но могу предложить Вам альтернативу

```
<c:forEach var="listItem" items="${answer}">

    //Работа с каждым элементом отдельно использую ${listItem} 

</c:forEach>
```

Вы так же можете для эксперимента попробывать вывести тип элемента list в вашей jsp, чтобы убедиться, что произошла правильная конвертация

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет! Я пока не сталкивался с JSTL, но обязательно разберусь. На первый взгляд это кажется удобнее, чем скриплеты.